# Why does my blower turn on intermittently although no heat is called for?

Tags: hvac

My furnace is a Ruud Activia 90 Plus and the thermostat is a Lyric Round thermostat.  I have the thermostat set for 62 degrees in Heat Mode.  The indoor temp is currently 68. It seems as though the blower comes on by itself and runs for about one minute before shutting down.  While the blower is running I have a yellow fault light and the fault indicator is blinking once, off 2 seconds and repeating.  After a minute it shuts down for an hour or I can reset the power to the furnace to reset.  Regarding the thermostat, I have no C wire, but installed a C wire adaptor between the thermostat and the control board.  This has been in place for several months with no problem. I unplugged the thermostat from the wall and also removed the battery in the base plate and the blower still came on without the thermostat in place

Comment: Great job Sherlock. It is not the thermostat. Your furnace has multiple sensor for its operation and those have nothing to do with thermostat.

Comment: Can you get us an actual model number for your furnace please?

Comment: I didn’t see the model number when I opened the lower cover.  I took a picture of the electrical drawing that was inside, but I don’t see how I can attach it to this post.  As a follow-up, the blower has not come on for no reason since I restored the thermostat last evening.